# cakephp shell command changing tmp permissions

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, cron, centos

I'm running a CentOS server with CakePHP 2. I run a shell command every night via the console as a Cronjob.

I'm far from an expert on Linux but it seems that when the cron job runs, a different user assumes ownership of the files in the tmp directory (I'm running the crob job as root).

The following morning when I log onto my site via the web I get a dozen or so errors about file permissions in the tmp directory. I can chmod this files and the errors will all go away.... until the cron job runs again.

I checked around the web a bit and found one post suggesting that I add this to my core.php:

```
Cache::config('default', array(
'engine' => 'File',
'mask' => 0666,
 ));
```

I didn't have any effect. 
I would really appreciate some advice on how to get the owner of these tmp files to stop changing or how to make cakephp not throw up an error about it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: maybe you can add at the end of your cron job the chown command

Comment: What does the ownership of the file end up being? What are the permissions at that point? Why are you using files in a temporary directory (`/tmp`?) for real things?

Comment: @inye, That sounds like a pretty good idea. I'll have to see what the owner of the file is supposed to be and try to add that to the job

Comment: @EtanReisner, The ownership changes from root to apache. The permissions change as well but I'm not sure what to (it wont run again until tonight and i've already changed them back) They start at 777 though.
I'm not using files in a tmp directory for real things. It's something cakephp does automatically, it has to do with chaching for model data

Comment: It changes *to* `apache` and then something can't access it? `777` is a terrible mode for just about everything. If your cronjob is running as root it would be surprising for the files to end up owned by `apache` unless something was explicitly doing that. At which point I would ask why it thinks it should and why that change is breaking your site.

Comment: @EtanReisner, Like I said earlier, I'm not great with linux so please excuse me while i suffer my way through the details. The permission should be 664 with apache as the owner. After the cron job runs they are 664 with root as the owner. The cron job is running as root.

This is happening because the files themselves are cache files which get deleted and recreated automatically by cakephp. When root is running the cron job it creates/modifies files and takes ownership of them. I have no control over this.

Comment: Ah, so that's the other way around then. That makes much more sense. Is there a reason you are running this cron job as `root` instead of as the `apache` user? Doing that would probably solve your problem.

Comment: @EtanReisner, there is no reason that I am doing it as root. It is just the only way I knew how to set it up. How would I go about setting it up as apache? I did not create that account and do not know the password

Comment: The apache user almost certainly does not have a password. You should nonetheless be able to (as root) edit that users crontab and give it a cron job. `crontab -u apache -e`

Comment: @EtanReisner, I was able to change the cronjob to the apache user as you described. Hopefully the errors will be gone tomorrow. This is my first question on here but I would be happy to give you credit for the answer if I knew how...Thanks for all your help

Comment: Report back if it works. If it does I'll add that solution as an answer and then you should be able to accept it.